# Comparing two images and showing the difference in a new image?

Tags: computer-vision, image-recognition, image-preprocessing, opencv, image-segmentation

I would like to compare two web pages images using computer vision techniques.
Show what are non-unique portions comparing both images. Which part image1 not exist in  image2 vice versa.

[image: Web page image 1]

[image: Webpage Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

A simple and time efficent solution is the computation of the absoulte values of the difference image. This can be done as follows:

```
import cv2
img_a = cv2.imload([first_image_filename])
img_b = cv2.imload([second_image_filename])
img_diff = cv2.absdiff(img_a, img_b)
cv2.imshow('abs difference', img_diff)
cv2.waitKey(-1)
```

Comment: Thank you I can see the difference. Is it possible to ignore the same alphabets with different font sizes(Can we show as no difference)?

Comment: With such a low level analysis not. To ignore alphabets you would have to apply an optical character recognition (OCR) and than set regions with detected characters to 0.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to apply OCR and is there any similar kind of work or any blog.

Comment: I have got no specific blog in mind. Maybe https://www.learnopencv.com/tag/ocr/